# Java 8 LocalDate in hibernate wrongly mapped to TIMESTAMP

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, h2, java-time

I use Spring boot 1.4.2, which brings hibernate 5.0.11 (JPA 2.1).
I want to use the Java 8 time classes in my entities, and so included `hibernate-java8`.

My entity defines a LocalDate field.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_alarms_timeline", indexes = {...})
public class MyAlarm {
    ...
    @Column(name = "validity_date")
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate validityDate;
}
```

I expect this to be mapped to a DATE in my H2 database.

In my DB I declare this as `validity_date DATE NOT NULL,`.

When I try to run tests, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: 
    Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [validity_date] in table [my_alarms_timeline]; 
    found [date (Types#DATE)], but expecting [timestamp (Types#TIMESTAMP)]
```

To my surprise, if I change the DB definition to `validity_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,`  I get the error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: 
    Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [validity_date] in table [my_alarms_timeline]; 
    found [timestamp (Types#TIMESTAMP)], but expecting [date (Types#DATE)]
```

This is just the reverse message of the previous one.

I also tried, instead of including `hibernate-java8`, to use an `AttributeConverter<LocalDate, java.sql.Date>` but this produces the same error result.

**What must I do, so that my LocalDate is mapped correctly to a DATE in the DB?**

I also tried with a `LocalDateTime` field mapped to a TIMESTAMP, and this works without problems...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So I got it to run, by adding a `columnDefinition="DATE"` to the `@Column`annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_alarms_timeline", indexes = {...})
public class MyAlarm {
    ...
    @Column(name = "validity_date", columnDefinition = "DATE")
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate validityDate;
}
```

Not sure why nobody else is seeing this issue...

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4 which uses Hibernate 5.0.12. Weirdly enough one of the ZonedDateTime columns in my Entity object was being mapped to a MySQL VARBINARY...but the good news is, this fixed it!

Comment: got this `[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303138
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:863)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:355)
 at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)`

Comment: @jtcotton63 - Do you remember how you were able to change the column from a `VARBINARY` back to the ZonedDateTime? I'm facing a similar issue with H2.

Comment: @Bwvolleyball unfortunately, no, I don't. If adding the `columnDefinition = "DATE"` doesn't do it, then I'm not sure what will. That was a number of years ago, and I' don't have access to that code anymore :/

Comment: I do had this issue when we migrated from `JBoss 7.0` to `JBoss 7.2.4` *EAP*.

Comment: In my case this helped when my db column was of datetime type and entity was OffsetDateTime. I added columnDefinition = "datetime" and it worked

Answer (score 5):

I've not used this in Spring but in "standard" JPA, I've done something like:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class OffsetDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<OffsetDateTime, Timestamp> {
    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(OffsetDateTime entityValue) {
        if( entityValue == null )
            return null;

        return Timestamp.from(Instant.from(entityValue));
    }

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp databaseValue) {
        if( databaseValue == null )
            return null;

        return OffsetDateTime.parse(databaseValue.toInstant().toString());
    }
}
```

My table has "timestamp with timezone" columns.  My @Entity then uses OffsetDateTime.  You should be able to convert between your datatypes with something like this.

Comment: I also tried using an AttributeConverter<LocalDate, java.sql.Date> but this fails with the same error. I guess that's the approach of the hibernate-java8 package.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you have the following code somewhere in your project:

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })
```

If you are using Hibernate 5.x you should remove the reference to Jsr310JpaConverters.class otherwise both Hibernate and Spring will attempt to handle Java 8 Date and Time objects.  This can result in some very inconstant behaviour (such as LocalDate instances being persisted with the wrong value when running on machines that do not use UTC).

You should also remove any occurrences of:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "DATE")
```

If you require it, it is a indication that something is seriously wrong with your hibernate configuration.