# Spring Data LocalDate comparison fails (time is not ignored)

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, jpql

I got a Spring Boot app with an Oracle database. This is my repository and entity:

```
public interface CampaignRepository extends CrudRepository<Campaign, Long> {

    @Query("select k from Campaign k where k.validAfter <= :date")
    List<Campaign> findAllValidAfterDate(@Param("date") LocalDate date);
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@OtherAnnotations
public class Campaign{
    id and stuff...

    private LocalDate validAfter;

}
```

Now I would assume that if you put in `LocalDate.now()` into the function it should return all campaigns that are valid today. However this is NOT the case if I run a test against the Oracle which contains entries that are valid today where the time is after "now". The `validAfter` column is of type `DATE`.

Somehow the time part is not ignored in the `<=` comparison. Did someone experience this behaviour? How can I ensure that the time is ignored and only the date is used in the comparison?

I already tried this solution but it has no effect:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40525940/1528880

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no a straight way to persist a LocalDate in a JPA since the Java 8 LocalDate is younger then JPA and the JPA behavior in this case is unpredictable (actually is, but I think it's DB-depended behavior). You have to implement your own AttributeConverter to use LocalDate in entities. Here is an example:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)    
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {   
        @Override
        public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
            return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
        }
        @Override
        public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
            return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
        }
    }
```

And here is a nice article: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a `LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay()` which will produce `LocalDateTime` formed at the time of midnight, 00:00, meaning the start of today's date. So that only date will be used in comparison.

Comment: This would imply changing the type of `validAfter` to LocalDateTime which I would like to avoid as it has a whole different meaning.