# hibernate schema validation failure for LocalDate - found date, but expecting timestamp

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I had recently tried my application to deploy from JBoss EAP **7.0** to **7.2.4** and since then I am facing this issue with schema validation for fields with `LocalDate` mapped to the columns of `date` types.
The exact failure message is:

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"project-name.ear#MyPersistenceUnit\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [someDate] in table [SOME_TABLE]; found [date (Types#DATE)], but expecting [timestamp (Types#TIMESTAMP)]"}}
```

The snippet from schema:

```sql
create table SOME_TABLE(
  -- primiary key and other columns
  someDate date
);
```

The field in the entity:

```java
@Convert(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
private LocalDate someDate;
```

The converter

```java
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateConverter
    implements
    AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : Date.valueOf(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : dbData.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

I found that adding a `@Column(columnDefinition = "date")` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40525940/725306) solves the issue but my question is:

1. Do I necessarily need to force to add the `columnDefinition` in such cases?
2. The application works well in JBoss **7.0**. How can I know what changes introduced in JBoss **7.2.4** which break my application?
3. Any other recommendation to solve this issue.

---

This issue is with H2 while connecting with Oracle there is no such issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

Seems you hit a incompatibility of Hibernate with H2 driver while working with DATE in Oracle MODE. See: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1824

Besides, JBoss 7.2 now supports JPA 2.2 (See: https://access.redhat.com/articles/113373). In JPA 2.2 support where added for Java8 time classes like LocalDate, so you can remove your converter.

JPA 2.2 uses JDBC 4.2. Here are the object mappings in JDBC.

See Table B-4 on [JDBC 4.2 spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-spec/jdbc4.2-fr-spec.pdf):

[image: Table B-4 on JDBC 4.2 spec]

Comment: Removing the `@Convert` annotation works. But why it has an impact on the datatype during schema validation?

Comment: JPA 2.2 uses JDBC 4.2. The mapping for the type LocalDate in JDBC 4.2 is DATE. With the converter, schema generation uses java.util.Date as the object type that needs to map, and in JDBC java.util.Date is mapped to TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Note that JPA has the @Temporal annotation, for java.util.Date fields that lets you use a DATE instead of the default TIMESTAMP

Comment: Thanks @areus for the explanation. Is there some reference links to support your first comment?

Comment: I added the table of mappings for objects in JDBC 4.2.

Comment: Thanks @areus. But I needed a link/reference in support of your statement `With the converter, schema generation uses java.util.Date as the object type that needs to map`. Hope I am not too much demanding.

Comment: See Hibernate 5.3 doc,  _With a custom AttributeConverter, the application developer can map a *given JDBC type* to an entity basic type_. "https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-jpa-convert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209859/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-areus).

Comment: Thanks for the update. But I do not think this issue is related to Oracle mode in H2. Today I tested the same on PostgreSQL and had the same issue. Your suggestion to remove the `@Convert`er works well but I am afraid this will break our applications compatibility with WebSphere.

Comment: Removing the convert annotation fixed the issue. Tested this with H2, postgreSQL and Oracle on JBoss EAP 7.0, 7.2.4 and WebSphere 9.x. On WebSphere I needed to add the `hibernate-java8` dependency to make `LocalDate` work. But I still unable to understand why the datatype was changed due to that.