# Enabling @Converter in @DataJpaTest

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I am trying to save a LocalDate via JPA. Following this guide: https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/ I implemented a converter.

Now this works just fine.

However, I have a few RepositoryTests that are annotated with @DataJpaTest that are supposed to use this converter.

Those are broken now. I get something along the line of

```
wrong column type encountered in column [...] in table [...]; found [date (Types#DATE)], but expecting [timestamp (Types#TIMESTAMP)]
```

Which is the exact reason I added the damn converter. So apparently the Converter is not picked up and used in the Context of @DataJpaTest.
How can I change that?

The embeddable Class in Question:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Embeddable
public class MyEntity {
    @Column
    private LocalDate dateToStore;
}
```

The converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {
   
    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate();
    }

}
```

I´m using Hibernate 5.4.20.Final
With Spring Boot 2.3.3
Also Liquibase, this is the changeset:

```
<changeSet>   
    <addColumn tableName="tableName">
        <column name="DATE_TO_STORE" type="DATE"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeset>
```

The breaking Test is simple, it just looks like this:

```
@DataJpaTest
class MyRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Test
    void save(){
        myRepository.save(new MyEntity());
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please show us the offending code, as well as the entities in question

Comment: As a side note, which Hibernate version are you using? The latest Hibernate versions have pretty decent support for `java.time` types, eliminating the need for a custom converter

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514341/java-8-localdate-in-hibernate-wrongly-mapped-to-timestamp/40525940)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that @DataJpaTest doesn't scan for @Converter classes as can be seen in the [Spring Doc - Testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)

Relevant Part for @WebMvcTest (working correctly):

> To test whether Spring MVC controllers are working as expected, use
> the @WebMvcTest annotation. @WebMvcTest auto-configures the Spring MVC
> infrastructure and limits scanned beans to @Controller,
> @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter, GenericConverter,
> Filter, WebMvcConfigurer, and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver

Where as @DataJpaTest:

> You can use the @DataJpaTest annotation to test JPA applications. By
> default, it scans for @Entity classes and configures Spring Data JPA
> repositories

This might be a Bug in Spring as loading Converters should always be relevant for JPA Tests in my opinion (similar to this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/4e88db9883c6db6bc6c8c6c9c6d84723129cf0ba)).

My fix is to manually load the converters in the test by adding a new exclude filter to the test:

```
@DataJpaTest
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = true)
@TypeExcludeFilters(DataJpaTypeExcludeFilterWithConverter.class)
class SomeTest {
...
}
```

The custom Filter:

```
public class DataJpaTypeExcludeFilterWithConverter extends StandardAnnotationCustomizableTypeExcludeFilter<DataJpaTest> {
        private static final Set<Class<?>> DEFAULT_INCLUDES;

        static {
            Set<Class<?>> includes = new LinkedHashSet<>();
            includes.add(Converter.class);
            includes.add(GenericConverter.class);
            try {
                includes.add(Module.class);
            }
            catch (Throwable ex) {
                // ignore
            }
            DEFAULT_INCLUDES = unmodifiableSet(includes);
        }

        protected DataJpaTypeExcludeFilterWithConverter(Class<?> testClass) {
            super(testClass);
        }

        @Override
        protected Set<Class<?>> getDefaultIncludes() {
            return DEFAULT_INCLUDES;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Converters (in this case) are a JPA concern and will be loaded by the JPA provider, this is not the task of Spring nor Spring Data (JPA) to manage these converters. The converters mentioned in the MVC testing are the Spring converter implementations and have no relation to JPA.