# H2 fails to fetch Instant when using native query [Spring Boot 3]

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I just migrated an application to Spring Boot 3 and Spring 6, also getting the newest version of h2(2.1.214) for my unit tests. I have a native query looking something like this:

```
@Query(value = "select id as id, time as time from table", nativeQuery = true)
List<Projection> getMyProjection();
```

and I am fetching this into a projection:

```
public interface Projection{
    Long getId();
    Instant getTime();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Up until now, I was testing this in a DataJpaTest using h2 and it was working just fine.
Since my Spring Boot 3 upgrade, I am getting this error when trying to fetch that Instant field:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot project java.time.OffsetDateTime to java.time.Instant; Target type is not an interface and no matching Converter found

There is no documentation about this issue and I think it's a rather new one since Spring Boot 3 is pretty recent.
Did anyone encounter this? Or do you have any advice?
Thanks!

There was not much I could do about it.
I think it's worth mentioning that I can't translate my query to a Jpa non-native one since some of the MySql features used in the query are not supported in Jpa.

Comment: Have you tried to use java.time.OffsetDateTime instead of Instant in your Projection class? Or you have to use Instant?

Comment: All the application flow uses Instant. It would be weird to change that just for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in this [H2 thread](https://groups.google.com/g/h2-database/c/STMG9lENz90), the most convenient solution for your problem seems to be defining a custom JPA converter, akin to the [Jsr10Converters](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/convert/Jsr310Converters.java), which makes an OffsetDateTime into an Instant (you'll also have to write the vice-versa converter). Although the responder in the H2 thread says the problem is not an issue with H2 per se, it seems like there is a bug out there that makes the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type in H2 not be convertible to Java's `Instant`.

You will have to write a Filter that catches up your converter, as the `@DataJpaTest` does not scan for user-defined convertors by default. You can import it then to you test-classes as done [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65305451/3214777).