# Spring and TestNG @DataJpaTest does not run AttributeConverters for @Convert annotated attributes

Tags: java, spring, jpa, testng, h2

I have a very basic `AttributeConverter` implementation that I want to test. As such, I'll first apply a simple hash, but instead of un-hashing I'll just throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

```java
public class EncryptorConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, byte[]> {
    @Override
    public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        // Apply hash
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] dbData) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

And an entity

```java
@Entity
public class Account {
  @Id
  private String id;
  @Column
  @Convert(converter = EncryptorConverter.class)
  private String sensitiveInfo;
}
```

And let's say I have a very fundamental repository for `Account`:

```java
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, String> {
}
```

I want to make sure that my `EncryptorConverter` is being called in a `@DataJpaTest`, like this:

```java
@DataJpaTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = {LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AccountRepositoryTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {
  @Autowired
  private AccountRepository accountRepository;

  public void shouldSaveEncryptedData() throws Exception {
    Account expectedAccount = new Account("1", "sensitive info");
    accountRepository.save(expectedAccount);

    // I was expecting an exceptioon with UnsupportedOperationException as root cause here
    Optional<Account> actualAccount = accountRepository.findById("1");

    assertTrue(actualAccount.isPresent());
    assertEquals(actualAccount.get(), expectedAccount);
  }
}
```

I expected the aforementioned test to fail, but instead it passes. All debug I made suggested that the entity was persisted without any encryption in the DB. I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025746/enabling-converter-in-datajpatest) article, which seemed more promising for the problem I'm facing, but it didn't help much.

Does someone know what to do here?

---

Extra: this is how I'm configuring my test DB:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"..."})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestDatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("...");
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: I doub a select is even being issued. Do a `saveAndFlush` and inject the `TestEntityManager` and call clear on that. This as to clear the 1st level cache, then do a `findById` so that a query is actually being issued. Your `TestDatabaseConfig` doesn't add anything, only makes things worse. Shouldn't the converter be annotated with `@Converter` as well for it to be registered?

Comment: In additional, the article/answer you link to is wrong. Spring Data JPA will not scan for `@Converter` because simply it shouldn't as that is part of the JPA specification which will scan for those classes. Next to that it was about global converters not for converters on specific fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the fact that the converter isn't being picked up, the problem is your test and lack of understanding of how Hibernate works.

You are saving the entity, which puts it in the first level cache, next you do a `findById` which will result in an `EntityManager.find` which will first look into the 1st level cache and as the entity is found no query nor conversion will take place.

To fix, simulate a transaction. For this inject the `TestEntityManager` into your class and `flush` and `clear` after the `save`. This will issue the SQL to the database and clear the 1st level cache.

```java
@DataJpaTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = {LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AccountRepositoryTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {
  
  @Autowired
  private TestEntityManager tem;

  @Autowired
  private AccountRepository accountRepository;

  @Test
  public void shouldSaveEncryptedData() throws Exception {
    Account expectedAccount = new Account("1", "sensitive info");
    accountRepository.save(expectedAccount);
    
    // Simulate commit/tx end
    tem.flush();
    tem.clear();

    Optional<Account> actualAccount = accountRepository.findById("1");

    assertTrue(actualAccount.isPresent());
    assertEquals(actualAccount.get(), expectedAccount);
  }
}
```